# How can markdown the national flags in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I want to insert images of national flags from a URL source and Markdown code block in Jupyter Notebooks as following examples:

[image: Flags]

I have found a similar method they used **flag codes** in excel
Like this:

```
|Teams          | Nationality flag  |
| ------------- |:-----------------:|
| Germany       |  GER              |
| Iran          |  IRI              |
| Italy         |  ITA              |
```

Any helps will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Just like you do in SO
- In a markdown cell, create the markdown table, add the link to the image file, and run the cell.

  - [image]
- Flags from [Flagpedia](https://flagpedia.net/)

### Style 1: In a Markdown Cell

```py
|Teams          | Nationality flag  |
| ------------- |:-----------------:|
| CA            |  ![](http://usa.flagpedia.net/data/flags/mini/ca.png)              |
```

### Style 2: In a Markdown Cell

```py
|Teams          | Nationality flag  |
| ------------- |:-----------------:|
| CA            |  ![][ca]          |

  [ca]: http://usa.flagpedia.net/data/flags/mini/ca.png
```

### Style 3: In a Markdown Cell

```py
|Teams          | Nationality flag  |
| ------------- |:-----------------:|
| CA            |  ![ca]            |

  [ca]: http://usa.flagpedia.net/data/flags/mini/ca.png
```

### All styles produce

[image]

- Attribution [How to show images inside Table?](https://exploratory.io/note/kanaugust/Showing-Images-inside-Table-YCO6Yst1CA)